# Finding the resonating frequency

Tags: passive-networks, resonance

Here in the given figure is a parallel circuit. The goal is to find the resonating frequency (**\$f_0\$**). How can we find out the resonating frequency in that case? This formula won't work i guess.

$$\omega_0 = \sqrt {\frac {1}{LC}\ -\ \left ( \frac {R}{L} \right )^2}$$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDeHGUm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: See http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/parres.html#c1

Comment: Are you trying to find the natural resonant frequency or the frequency at which the impedance has a phase angle of zero degrees?

Comment: What do you mean with "formula...won`t work"? Cannot be applied? Why not? This implies that you have a suitable definition for the resonance case. Have you?

Comment: That looks like it may be a trick question.

Comment: \$f_o=1/(2\pi\sqrt{LC})\$ ? The only effect the series R will have is alter its Q factor...

Comment: How can you expect that formula to work, given that it only takes into account a single resistance value whereas you have two resistance values in your circuit? Doesn't makes sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

As @Steve Roehrs explained this problem can be approached with the Laplace transform. Using the Laplace transforms of the inductor and capacitor we get the following expression for the total impedance.

$$H = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{L s + R_{2}} + \frac{1}{R_{1} + \frac{1}{C s}}}$$

$$= \frac{C L R_{1} s^{2} + (C R_{1} R_{2}+L) s+ R_{2}}{C L s^{2} + (C R_{1} + C R_{2}) s + 1}$$

In order to get at the resonant frequency we have to evaluate the Laplace transform on the jw-axis, s = jw.

As has been mentioned previously, you need to understand what exactly you are looking for, minimum impedance, minimum phase, or something else.

We can gain some insight by graphing the expressions for the phase and magnitude of H as a function of frequency. Specifically a Bode Plot.

$$20log(|H|) = 20log\left(\left|\frac{C L R_{1} (j\omega)^{2} + (C R_{1} R_{2}+L) (j\omega)+ R_{2}}{C L (j\omega)^{2} + (C R_{1} + C R_{2}) (j\omega) + 1}\right|\right)$$

[image]

$$angle(H) = tan^{-1}{\frac{Im(H)}{Re(H)}}$$

[image]

Here we can see that we can solve for the resonant point by setting the derivative of |H| equal to zero and solving for w. Similarly we could set the angle of H to zero and solve for w.

If you follow that procedure and solve, the resulting expression for the resonant frequency is:

$$ \omega = \frac{1}{\sqrt{LC}}$$

Comment: The "resonant point" is not identical to the "resonant frequency" which requires zero phase shift (real input impedance).

Answer (score 0):

Laplace transforms will do it - if I can remember enough of my second year EE.

The signal generator on the left is getting in the way - I'm assuming you want the resonant frequency of the parallel RL/RC circuit.

Define the impedance of the resistors as R

Define the impedance of the capacitor as 1/sC

Define the impedance of the inductor as sL

Calculate the total impedance of the circuit (without the generator) as X(s) by summing the impedances in each branch and using the law for parallel resistors

R = 1/ (1/R1 + 1/R2)

Substitute s = jw

The magnitude of the impedance of your circuit is |X(s)|

Find the derivative of that  d ( |X(s)| ) / ds

Solve for s=0

Knowing s= j * 2 * pi * f

solve for f.

Sorry if the formatting is a mess.

Comment: Reference : https://stanford.edu/~boyd/ee102/laplace_ckts.pdf

Comment: I think, you should point to the fact that YOU have used a definition based on the maximum of the complex impedance (first derivative=0). However, this does NOT apply for each circuit - and I think, for the given circuit we must apply the phase criterion (in the Stanford link, there is a very basic circuit where both definitions are applicable).

Answer (score 0):

The formula for Series or Parallel resonance is:

$$\omega_0 = \frac {1}{\sqrt {LC}}$$

Gives a \$\omega_0\$ = 2236.1 rad/s and a resonant frequency \$f_0\$ = 355.9Hz.

From [hyperphysics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/parres.html#c1) (which is referenced in the OP comments):

$$\omega_0 = \frac {1}{\sqrt {LC}}\  \sqrt {\frac {R_L^2C - L}{R_C^2C - L} \ } $$

Gives a \$\omega_0\$ = 2263.6 rad/s and \$f_0\$ = 360.3Hz or 1.23% from the pure formula.

Given the accuracies of the components involved (say 5%), \$\omega_0 = \frac {1}{\sqrt {LC}}\$ will be more than accurate.

Answer (score 0):

One only has to look at the impedance chart of the general purpose LC components you have chosen to realize these are very low Q parts.  Normally you drive a parallel LC tank circuit with a current source ( Common emitter) to get a high Q resonant frequency as the R/Xc(f) = Q   where Xc(f)=Xl(f) at resonance.

But you can see at the resonant frequency of these LC parts the Zo<1Ω meanwhile the ESR of each part is >1Ω making each component more resistive than reactive, which makes the tank cct underdamped and not resonant at all.

Why these parts ? and what are you trying to achieve ? a cheap RLC meter? a tank circuit? a test method for resonance? or what?

[image]

**FYI low ESR high Q E-caps have a ESR*C =T value < 10us. 
Yours is in the General Purpose (G.P.) range of 100us and poor for resonance.**